# how to validate input values using javascript/ajax on local drive without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am going to share a lesson on HTML format for students who will run it on their local computers. I want the learners to able to check the answers, which they will write into the inputs. 
Once they run it localy, the address bar for answers sheet looks like this:

> file:///D:/XAMPP/htdocs/ielts/modules/reading/answers_sheet.html

the input areas are looking like this:

```
<td class="reading">
    <input type="text" name="01" class="txt " maxlength="50" value="">
</td>
<td class="reading">
    <input type="text" name="02" class="txt " maxlength="50" value="">
</td>
...
........
<input type="button" class="button" name="check" id="check" value="Check your answers" onclick="submit();">
```

after they enter their response and click on "check your answers" button, it should look like this:

```
<td class="reading">
    <img src="/images/correct.gif" style="float:right;">
    <input type="text" name="01" class="txt " maxlength="50" value="premises">
</td>
<td class="reading">
    <img src="/images/wrong.gif" style="float:right;">
    <span class="correct_anwser">(premises)</span>
</td>
```

Can you help me to create a script that would check the answers and show if they are correct or not. I would appreciate any feedback on this subject.

Comment: You're basically asking how to create a clientside application, which is certainly possible but far too broad a question to be answerable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to the bottom of the HTML document:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // List your answers to match the "name" attribute of the input
    // with the key ("01", "02", etc) of this object
    var correctAnswers = {
        "01": "alpha",
        "02": "beta",
        "03": "delta"
    }

    // Click on the check button
    $("#check").on("click", function() {
      // Clear results of previous submission
      $(".img-box").empty();

      // Loop through each element that has the "reading" class
      $(".reading").each(function(index) {

          // Find the input contained in each reading element
          var input = $(this).find('input').first();
          // Get the value for the "name" attribute
          var reading = $(input).attr("name");
          // Get the input value
          var value = $(input).val();

          // Check if the value matches the value of the element in the
          // correctAnswers object
          if (value == correctAnswers[reading]) {
              // Insert the "correct" image if it does
              $(this).prepend('<div class="img-box"><img src="/images/correct.gif" style="float:right;"></div>');
          } else {
              // Insert the "incorrect" image if it does not
              $(this).prepend('<div class="img-box"><img src="/images/wrong.gif" style="float:right;"></div>');
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

You should be able to see it working [on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uw7ex1OPRXokTdrlxtnX?p=preview)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you Shaun so much.

Comment: I would like to go further and calculate the total score. I tried to edit the script on Plunker. I tried to give 1 point for each correct answer and count all the correct answers and show the total correct answers. Please see it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/cWWk2lH75hiXPEjQzOd6  Unfortunately it gives 1 point for incorrect answers as well. Can you help me please?

Comment: @hijacker83 Is this what your going for? (the new code is commented): https://plnkr.co/edit/ySK2JaNmWTX4xizIA2D0?p=preview

Comment: Thank you again Shaun. I need to show the score next to the each answer as well.  I tried to do it here https://plnkr.co/edit/jwJx2UuC2PS6XM3OODoS?p=preview it's almost working. when all the answers are correct it shows 1 point. but when 1 answer is correct and the second answer is wrong it shows 0 point for both. It suppose to give 1 point for the correct answer. I would appreciate if you could kindly help me with this. This will be my last request.

Comment: I made it to work here plnkr.co/edit/uWv1AW6rVzaK2LQAzoT8?p=preview but I had to give class names like points01, points02, points03. Is there any way to make it work with the same class name?

Comment: Here's one way to do it with some comments: https://plnkr.co/edit/eqpHGbIQEiRNigDwBO30?p=preview . If you are going to be working with jQuery a lot, you could check out https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery . They have some interactive lessons will provide a good foundation.

Comment: great. thank you. I bookmarked it. I would like to learn jquery. more I sit infront of this computer more things come to my mind. Now I would like to try it with radio element. https://plnkr.co/edit/4A32PdQl094clBF8tE2q?p=preview here I have chosen gama which is wrong answer but gives me 1 point. Can you help me with this one please?

Comment: The `var input = _this.find('input').first();` line is going to prevent the radio buttons from working properly, so you would have to rework the solution quite a bit. You should post a new question, since this current question has been flagged for deletion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102500/discussion-between-hijacker83-and-shaun).